# Set maximum character amount on TextAreaFor in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc

I would like to control how many characters users can write in TextAreaFor.

How can I do it, with a remaining counter if characters under the textarea??

My TextAreaFor looks like that:

```
<%= Html.TextAreaFor(m => m.Answer,7,72,null) %>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not the control itself. You just can't do that with a textarea. I found this weirder in webforms when you can on `<asp:TextBox` but not on `<asp:TextBox Mode="MultiLine"`

Anyway, it is just HTML's problem not ASP.NET MVC's. You will need JavaScript (or make it a TextBox)

Answer (score 1):

You need to [use javascript](http://www.mediacollege.com/internet/javascript/form/limit-characters.html) in order to achieve this or [if you prefer jQuery](http://www.devcurry.com/2009/08/limit-number-of-characters-in-textarea.html).